# returning values from list for indexes that are outside the range of the list with C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list. If the value that you've entered is within that list - result will be returned. Even if value is outside the result's range - result will be returned because of mod %. **It's really hard to explain my problem with words, so lets take a look at the code**:

```
        List<int> list1 = new List<int>(){ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int value = 3; // what's this number to us?
        string result = "";
        int starting_number = 3;

        if (value == list1[(list1.IndexOf(starting_number) + 2) % list1.Count()])
        { result = "yeah"; }
        else if (value == list1[(list1.IndexOf(starting_number) + 1) % list1.Count()])
        { result = "cool"; }
        else if (value == list1[(list1.IndexOf(starting_number) + 0) % list1.Count()])
        { result = "one"; }
        else if (value == list1[(list1.IndexOf(starting_number) - 1) % list1.Count()])
        { result = "noo"; }
        else {result = "oops cant find it"; }
```

- starting_number. This number is constant. All measurments are made in relation to this number.
- value - the value that we've entered. we need to get the result for this value
- result - just a string

**That's how it works:**

starting_number = 3, value = 2 => result = "noo" (because 2 = IndexOf(starting_number)- 1)

starting_number = 6, value = 0 => result = "cool" **(6 + 1 = 0)**

starting_number = 0, value = 6 => **Error will occur. (0 - 1 = 6)**

**any ideas how to improve the code to get rid of this error? Basically I can grab values is they are "after" starting_number, but I cant grab them "before" starting_number.**

- in case of **(6 + 1 = 0)**: list looks like this 6,0,1,2,3...
- in case of **(0 - 1 = 6)**: list should be this ...4,5,6,0

if you have any questions please ask.. it's really hard to explain the problem with words, but I guess examples made it more clear.

how do you grab values that are below starting_number?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question...

Comment: any ideas how to improve the code to get rid of this error? Basically I can grab values is they are "after" starting_number, but I cant grab them "before" starting_number.

Comment: which leads us to: **how do you grab values that are below starting_number?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to map all integers to range 0 to Count-1 and your current formula is `x % count` which works only when `x > 0`. Then if you want it to work for all values of `x` try this one `(x % count + count) % count`

Comment: @Alex it can't also work, since Likurgs one gives you different number than mine when starting_index <= 0

Answer (score 1):

Try use this code

```
list1[Math.Sign((list1.IndexOf(starting_number) - 1))*(list1.IndexOf(starting_number) - 1) % list1.Count()]
```